# MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist while building project on SonarQube server

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, csproj

I have a postbuild target in my csproj file, as below.

```
 <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet publish '..\..\src\httpapi\httpapi.csproj' -o $(OutputPath)\service"/>
  </Target>
```

Runs without any issues on my local machine, but fails with below error while building on sonarqube server.

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. 
- Switch: '..\..\src\httpapi\httpapi.csproj'
```

any idea why this happens? is there any other way I can mention the path to the target project in my post build target?

Comment: afaik, SonarQube is used for code analysis, why do you need to build and publish code on it?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - yes, SonarQube is for code analysis, but the builds the project before analysis. I'm using this build target in my integaration tests project, to publish the target web api proj (for which integration test are written) to a separate folder in project output.

Comment: I'm getting the same error (MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist) in Team City, when I try to deploy my project. I'm using .NET core 3.1. The build gets successful in local, but fails to deploy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to to change below part to get this working

```
'..\..\src\httpapi\httpapi.csproj'
```

to

```
../../src/httpapi/httpapi.csproj
```

by removing quotes and changing the backward slash to forward slash..